# Pandas - revert many hot encoded (dummy variables)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Assuming I have the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'val': [5, 5, 10],
                   'trig_aaa': [1, 0, 1], 'trig_bbb': [0, 1, 1], 'trig_ccc': [0, 0, 1]})
print(df)

   id  val  trig_aaa  trig_bbb  trig_ccc
0   1    5         1         0         0
1   2    5         0         1         0
2   3   10         1         1         1
```

I'd like to turn it to the following df:

```
   id  val             trig
0   1    5            [aaa]
1   2    5            [bbb]
2   3   10  [aaa, bbb, ccc]
```

is there an elegant (hopefully, functionality pre-built) in Pandas/Python/Numpy?

### EDIT 1:

After looking at jpps' comment, a better processing to the DataFrame would looks like so:

```
   id  val trig
0   1    5  aaa
1   2    5  bbb
2   3   10  aaa
3   3   10  bbb
4   3   10  ccc
```

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar it's not really a duplicate because this example can be many hot, not just one hot so the accepted answers there won't work as they only return the first hot feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
# rename columns and melt dataframe
df.columns = [i if '_' not in i else i.split('_')[1] for i in df]
res = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'val'], var_name='trig')

# filter for 1 values and sort
res = res[res['value'].eq(1)].sort_values('id').iloc[:, :-1].reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)

   id  val trig
0   1    5  aaa
1   2    5  bbb
2   3   10  aaa
3   3   10  bbb
4   3   10  ccc
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to `res['value'].eq(1)` over `res['value']==1`?

Comment: @Dan, No difference, they mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Excellent!!! I'd use `df.columns = [i if str(i).startswith('trig_') is not True else i[len('trig_'):] for i in df]` for a more general purpose